# Nested `ImportError` on Py3 but not on Py2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, import, package

I'm having trouble understanding how nested imports work in a python project. For example:

```
test.py
package/
    __init__.py
    package.py
    subpackage/
        __init__.py
```

`test.py`:

```
import package
```

`package/__init__.py`:

```
from .package import functionA
```

`package/package.py`:

```
import subpackage

def functionA():
    pass
```

In Python 3.5 when I run `test.py` I get the following error, but no error in Python 2.7:

```
C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/importtest/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/importtest/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\importtest\package\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .package import functionA
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\importtest\package\package.py", line 1, in <module>
    import subpackage
ImportError: No module named 'subpackage'
```

However if I run `package.py` with Python 3.5. I get no error at all.

This seems strange to me as when `package.py` is run on its own the line `import subpackage` works, but with it is being 'run' (don't know if this is the right terminology here) through the nested import, the same line cannot find `subpackage`.

Why are there differences between Python 2.7 and 3.5 in this case and how can this be resolved in a way that works for both 2.7.x and 3.x?

I think this might be due to the fact that `import subpackage` in the nested import counts as an implicit relative import in the nested import but not when `package.py` is run directly, but if I do `import .subpackage` instead, I get this error on both 2.7 and 3.5:

```
C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/importtest/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Patrick/Desktop/importtest/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\importtest\package\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .package import functionA
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\importtest\package\package.py", line 1
    import .subpackage
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to run `package.py` on its own.

Comment: Thanks. The point was just trying to understand why `subpackage` could be imported one way and not the other. Of course there is no reason to run `package.py`.

Comment: In that case see [_Relative imports for the billionth time_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: @martineau I've actually read that post a couple of months back but for some reason it makes more sense now. Funny how that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
from . import subpackage
```

in `package/package.py`.

Comment: @pylang what do you mean?

Comment: What part of "in `package/package.py`" was unclear? You know, the one with `import subpackage` in it in your question.